# Oracle apex Pagination Scheme :Row Ranges 1-15 16-30 (with set pagination)

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using

```
Pagination Scheme :Row Ranges 1-15 16-30 (with set pagination)
```

What i need to do and i didn't found how is to use this pagination Schema but with max number of ranges 6 and not 5 as default in this pagination set.

Comment: When you say "max 6 and not max 5" are you talking about the number of ranges `1-15`, `16-30`, ... that APEX lists before `Next Set`?  If so I don't believe there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: yes I talk about number of ranges.

Comment: OK, so I think the answer is "no".